# Custom CSS Property in Custom Sharepoint 2010 WebPart

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm working on my first web part and was wondering if there is a way to create a custom resource (like a WPProperty) that would link CSS to the webpart just as you can control the XSLT of a XSLTViewPart (which, ironically I'm inheriting from). The reason for this is we're looking to make a shareable resource that would work with different lists that we want to represent differently.

I was thinking of adding a CSSLink or CSSRegistration into the code-behind, but then I thought it would be packaged along with the .DLL and not editable. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

To add a CSS file to a Web Part you can do following.

1. Map Layouts folder in Visual Studio
2. Add CSS file to the Mapped Folder (i.e.: If the Project Name is SPTest then add the file to Layouts/SPTest/ folder)

Then add following code to the WebPart's .ascx file

```
<Sharepoint:CssLink ID="CssLink1" runat="server" />
<SharePoint:CssRegistration ID="CssRegistration1" Name="/_layouts/SPTest/Test.css" runat="server" />
```

SharePoint 2010 doesn't really need the Sharepoint:CssLink.